# Google Apps Script (Docs) slow using user prompt

Tags: google-apps-script

I have managed to create a template generator (use case structure) for a specific document (Project specifications for students). It is working, but the problem is it is quite slow when interacting with the user using ui.prompt().

It is not recommended to use the browser prompt, because it is sometime blocked. So how can I improve my code?

I also have tried to log the timestamp for each call to the prompt, but it does not seem to work with ui calls.

Just copy paste my mess to try it out... (The text is in french)

```
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var body = doc.getBody();

function onOpen() {
    var menu = DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('Modèle');
    menu.addItem("Use case", 'addUseCaseTemplate').addToUi();
    menu.addItem("Use case (Wizard)", 'addUseCaseWizard_ui').addToUi();
    menu.addItem("TEST", 'test').addToUi();
}


function addUseCaseTemplate() {
  logFunction(arguments.callee.toString());

  var data = {
    title : '',
  };

  var index = getCursorIndex();
  addUseCaseTemplate_full(index, data);
}

function addUseCaseWizard_ui() {
  logFunction(arguments.callee.toString());

  addUseCaseWizard();
}

// Utilisation de l'assistant de cas d'utilisation
function addUseCaseWizard() {
  var wizardTitle = 'Assistant';

  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();

  var data = {
    title : '',
    description : '',
    actorsMain : '',
    actorsSecondary : '',
  };


  // Titre
  Logger.log("Prompt --> Title");
  var resp_title = ui.prompt(wizardTitle, "What is the use case title?", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  if (resp_title.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
    data.title = resp_title.getResponseText();

    var resp_desc = ui.prompt(wizardTitle, "Write a brief", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    var resp_actPrinc = ui.prompt(wizardTitle, "Who are the main actors? (Eg : Manager, Salesman)", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL)
    var resp_actSec = ui.prompt(wizardTitle, "Who are the secondary actors? (Ex : Manager, Salesman)", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL)


    if (resp_desc.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK)
      data.description = resp_desc.getResponseText();


    if (resp_actPrinc.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK)
      data.actorsMain = resp_actPrinc.getResponseText();

    if (resp_actSec.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK)
      data.actorsSecondary = resp_actSec.getResponseText();

    // Ajout de la structure ici!
    var index = getCursorIndex();
    addUseCaseTemplate_full(index, data);

  }
}

function test() {

  DocumentApp.getUi().alert("Cursor index : " + getCursorIndex());
  logFunction(arguments.callee.toString());
}

// Retourne l'index du curseur
function getCursorIndex() {
  logFunction(arguments.callee.toString());
  var cursor = doc.getCursor();
  var index = -1;

  if (cursor)
  {

    var uc = cursor.insertText("").getParent().asParagraph();

    index = body.getChildIndex(uc);
  }

  return index;
}

// Permet de générer un modèle complet de cas d'utilisation.
// Paramètres :
//   @index : Index de départ où insérer la structure
//   @data : JSON avec tous les éléments pour rédiger l'information
// Retour :
//   Index de la fin de la structure
function addUseCaseTemplate_full(index, data) {
  logFunction(arguments.callee.toString());

  index = addUseCaseTitle_full(index, data.title) + 1;
  index = addSummary_full(index, data) + 1;
  index = addEmptyParagraph(index) + 1;
  index = addUseCaseDetailed(index) + 1;
  index = addActors(index, data) + 1;
  index = addEmptyParagraph(index) + 1;
  index = addPreCondition(index) + 1;
  index = addEmptyParagraph(index) + 1;
  index = addScenario(index) + 1;
  index = addEmptyParagraph(index) + 1;
  index = addAlternativeChain(index) + 1;
  index = addEmptyParagraph(index) + 1;
  index = addErrorChain(index) + 1;
  index = addEmptyParagraph(index) + 1;

  return index;
}


function addUseCaseTitle(index) {
  logFunction(arguments.callee.toString());
  return addUseCaseTitle_full (index, '');
}

function addUseCaseTitle_full(index, title) {
  logFunction(arguments.callee.toString());


  var text = "Use case : " + title;
  var p = body.insertParagraph(index, text);
  p.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING3); 

  return index;  
}

function addSummary(index) {
  logFunction(arguments.callee.toString());

  return addSummary_full (index, data);
}

function addSummary_full(index, data) {
  logFunction(arguments.callee.toString());

  var text = "Summary";
  var p = body.insertParagraph(index++, text);
  p.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING4); 

  var cells = [
    ['Title : '],
    ['Brief : '],
    ['Actors : '],
    ["Création date : \t\t\t Update : "],
    ["Version : \t\t\t\t Responsible : "]
    ];

  var table = body.insertTable(index, cells);

  // Données du tableau
  if (data) {
    // TITRE    
    var title = data.title ? data.title : ' ';

    table.getRow(0).getCell(0).getChild(0).asParagraph()
      .appendText(title).setBold(false);

    // Description
    var description = data.description ? data.description : ' ';

    table.getRow(1).getCell(0).getChild(0).asParagraph()
      .appendText(description).setBold(false);

    // Acteurs
    var actors = data.actorsMain ? data.actorsMain : '';

    actors += data.actorsSecondary ? (actors != '' ? ', ' : '') + data.actorsSecondary : ''

    actors = actors != '' ? actors : ' ';

    table.getRow(2).getCell(0).getChild(0).asParagraph()
      .appendText(actors).setBold(false);
  }

  return index;  
}

// Titre Cas d'utilisation détaillé
function addUseCaseDetailed(index) {
  logFunction(arguments.callee.toString());

  var text = "Detailed use case";
  var p = body.insertParagraph(index, text);
  p.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING4); 

  return index;
}

// Ajoute une structure acteur
// Retourne l'index du dernier élément
function addActors (index, data) {
  logFunction(arguments.callee.toString());

  var text = "Actors";
  var p = body.insertParagraph(index++, text);
  p.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING5);

  var ls = body.insertListItem(index++, 'Main : ').setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);
  body.insertListItem(index, 'Secondary : ').setListId(ls);

  if (data)
  {
    if (data.actorsMain)
    {
      ls.getChild(0).asText().appendText(data.actorsMain).setBold(false);
    }

    if (data.actorsSecondary)
    {
      ls.getNextSibling().asText().appendText(data.actorsSecondary).setBold(false);
    }
  }

  return index;
}


// Ajout de la section precondition
function addPreCondition (index) {
  logFunction(arguments.callee.toString());

  var text = "Preconditions";
  var p = body.insertParagraph(index++, text);
  p.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING5); 

  var ls = body.insertListItem(index, '').setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);

  return index;
}

// Ajout de la section precondition
function addPostCondition (index) {
  logFunction(arguments.callee.toString());

  var text = "Postconditions";
  var p = body.insertParagraph(index++, text);
  p.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING5); 

  var ls = body.insertListItem(index, '').setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);

  return index;
}

// Ajout de la section scenario nominal
function addScenario (index) {
  logFunction(arguments.callee.toString());

  var text = "Main scenario ";
  var p = body.insertParagraph(index++, text);
  p.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING5);

  var ls = body.insertListItem(index, '');

  return index;
}

// Ajout de la section enchaînement alternative
function addAlternativeChain (index) {
  logFunction(arguments.callee.toString());

  var text = "Alternative scenario";
  var p = body.insertParagraph(index, text);
  p.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING5);

  return index;
}


// Ajout de la section enchaînement d'erreurs
function addErrorChain(index) {
  logFunction(arguments.callee.toString());

  var text = "Error scenario";
  var p = body.insertParagraph(index, text);
  p.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING5);

  return index;
}

// Ajout d'un paragraphe vide
function addEmptyParagraph(index) {
  logFunction(arguments.callee.toString());

  var text = "";
  var p = body.insertParagraph(index, text);
  p.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL);

  return index;
}

function logFunction(callee) {
  var log = {
    fnt : filterCalleeName(callee),
  };

  Logger.log(log);

  return log;
}

function filterCalleeName(callee) {
  var temp = callee.substr('function '.length);
  temp = temp.substr(0, temp.indexOf('('));

  return temp;
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop using prompt.
Build a ui with uiApp that has all the input fields and a button to enter them.
You can use a custom dialog or even better create a permanent sidebar: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars